# Email presentViewController is showing and removing itself

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I have two scenarios:

1) A `UIViewController` is creating `UINavigationControl` that opens another `UIViewController` on it a button that creates an email --> works great!

2) A `UIViewController` is creating `UINavigationControl` that opens a `UITableViewController` in `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method invokes scenario #1 **but this time the email is showing and immediately removes itself**

this is the code for creating scenario #2

The code for loading the `UITableview` into the `UINavigation`:

```
-(void)loadTableView
{
    UINavigationController *myNavigationController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"myNavigation"];
    myTableViewController* myTableViewController = (myTableViewController*)myNavigationController.viewControllers[0];
    myTableViewController.myDelegate = self;
    myTableViewController.navigationTitle = p_title;
    [self presentViewController:myNavigationController animated:NO completion:NULL];
}
```

The code for loading `UIViewController` from the `UITableView`

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    self.currentIndexPath = indexPath;
    if (self.currentIndexPath != nil)
    {
        myViewController* myViewController = (myViewController*)([self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"showContent"]);

        ...

        [self.navigationController pushViewController:myViewController animated:NO];
    }
}
```

any suggestion?

Comment: Here is something missing: `[self.navigationController myViewController animated:NO];`. Please update your question.

Comment: @dasdom where is it missing? it is the last line in the second code block

Comment: why don't you add that view controller as child view controller on navigationController like : [self.navigationController addChildViewController:myViewController]

Comment: @liva the `pushViewController` was missing. :)

Comment: @KrunalDarji instead of [self.navigationController pushViewController:myViewController animated:NO]; or in addition to (in the line before)?

Comment: Not in addition , replace pushviewcontroller with that..

Comment: @KrunalDarji i just tried it now myViewController doesn't show at all